# Track resource file modified or added items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I have many resource files in different Areas in asp.net and I am keeping all resource file data in client side local Storage (HTML 5).

I want to update local Storage if anything is modified on server side Resource file.

Don't try resource file modified time.

Many thanks.

Comment: some sample code of your efforts so far?

Comment: Is [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) what you are looking for ?

Comment: no i am using asp.net (HTML5). i just want if any new item in added in resource file or old item deleted from resource file. actually i have server resource copy on client side local Storage. in local Storage i have culture resource file in javascript varaible. i want to update that variable if anything change or added on server side resource file.